# Generate Enum from json in java

Tags: java, json, enums

I have json like:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Undefined"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Type A"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Type B"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Type C"}
]
```

How I can generate Enum dto like:

```
public enum OrderType {

  UNKNOWN(1, "Undefined"),
  TYPEA(2, "Type A"),
  TYPEB(3, "Type B"),
  TYPEC(4, "Type C");

  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  private WorkOrderType(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

?

I try do it with openapi-generator-maven-plugin, but it's not work, plugin generate Enum only with 1 field

Comment: Also I can use XSD, but it's not solve my problem

Comment: Why don't you just use the enum class from your question?

Comment: You can use `@JsonCreator`: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums#4-using-jsoncreator

Comment: @jurez, potentially there will be many such classes and their description will come in json/xsd, it would be more convenient to generate them at the compilation stage than to create them manually and copy the information

Comment: @ЕмилиянЙорданов, as far as I can see, an enum is manually created here and JsonCreator only fills it with values, this is not quite what you need